# getting sqlalche error of invalided transaction How to track it

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-devops, flask-sqlalchemy

[image]

Not able to try this error
Error Won't appear on local machine but when updated on Azure server it shows error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 528, in _invalid_transaction
raise exc.PendingRollbackError(
```

sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/8s2b)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Something has happened earlier in the code to invalidate the current transaction; you need to look further back in the logs to find the issue, and trigger a rollback there.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for your reply, I try to find it with scenarios but it never repeats on the same point